# Dyndns name not being resolved from LAN

Tags: networking, router, dyndns

I've got following network in my place:

ONT ---- Linksys E4300 @ DDWRT ---- Synology DS211J NAS (DynDNS client running) + 3 client WiFi machines

Problem is following:
When I run DynDNS on the router, IP is not getting updated. When I run DynDNS at NAS, IP gets updated but I'm not able to access NAS with DynDNS name from LAN.

I can access NAS from WAN with no problem on such setup but I need to use same names for LAN for testing. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your problem correctly, but i try to answer to this problem:

you cant access the NAS with the dyndns name from clients in the LAN?

If your clients look up the dyndns name the get back your IP in the internet and not the correct local address.

To correct that, you could edit the /etc/hosts, or the hostsfile on windows, adding the line

```
192.168.1.100 yournas.dyndns.org
```

of course you have to customize both the ip and the name.

If you do that you will be able to do tests from the lan.

Comment: It will not work because when i WAN it will overwrite DNS name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also install your own dns server on the nas. i used dnsmasq for this. dnsmasq is available via ipkg for your synology. you should use the option to use another hosts file, as the original /etc/hosts tends to be overwritten by synology